# Convert Pandas Column to Dict with Column Title as Key and Column Values as Values

Tags: python, pandas

So , example i have this dataframe:

```
ColA    ColB
AD      AC
BD      BC
CD      CC
DD      CD
```

how can i convert my df into some dictionary variable like this?

```
mydfDict = {'ColA' : ['AD','BD','CD','DD'] , 
            'ColB' : ['AC','BC','CC','CD'] 
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `join` and then [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.apply(','.join).to_dict()
print (d)
{'ColA': 'AD,BD,CD,DD', 'ColB': 'AC,BC,CC,CD'}
```

Detail:

```
print (df.apply(','.join))
ColA    AD,BD,CD,DD
ColB    AC,BC,CC,CD
dtype: object
```

But if want `list`s use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
print (df.to_dict(orient='list'))
{'ColA': ['AD', 'BD', 'CD', 'DD'], 'ColB': ['AC', 'BC', 'CC', 'CD']}
```